# Execute an eclipse web project in the console only?

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat

I am currently developing a web server. I am at a stage where 99% of the work is building the business logic, data logic and running tests. In other words, I have no need for the project to run in tomcat.

Right now, I created a test class that runs a mixture of the current code I am working on and prints info to the console. I have to restart the web server each time I make a change, which wastes a few minutes each time. Then I have to GET the localhost:8080 and wait for the page to load before I can read the printed output to the console.

Is it possible to run a Main type function that simply prints to the console without having to run trough tomcat.

Comment: Any class can have a Main method.  So, what is wrong with your test class?  You should be able to auto-deploy changes to a running server w/o having to re-start it.  At least, you can do that with Weblogic and JBoss.  Don't know about tomcat, but I would be surprised if not.

Comment: Learn about unit tests, and other kinds of automated tests. If you deploy the app every time you want to test some functionality or bug fix, you're doing it wrong.